# React Error: "Cannot update during an existing state transition"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to write an application that uses a toastr component. However, when I try and dispatch a redux action in this component I get the following console message:

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as
>   within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods
>   should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects
>   are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

You can see an example of this in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w6w8w810o8). Particularly, the issue is at the toastr.js component at line 23. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is exactly what the error message says: you're triggering a form of React state update directly inside of a `render()` method:

```js
const Toasts = ({ appointments, resetState, toastedAppointment, toasts }) => {
  if (toasts.type) {
    switch (toasts.type) {
      case "dataFetched":
        resetState(); // Dispatching this action creates the warning.
```

In this case it's dispatching a Redux action, but that ultimately results in a React `setState()` call.

Don't do that :)  Side effect logic, like triggering some kind of additional update based on current state, should probably happen in something like `componentDidUpdate`.  The `Toasts` component would probably need to be converted from a function component to a class component accordingly.

Comment: Exactly. You should not update the state inside `.render` because that's when the component state gets "pushed" onto the DOM. If, during your render, you do a conditional display based on a state property *then* modify this property, the elements pushed on the DOM will not be valid anymore, thus this React golden rule: **don't update the state during render**.

Comment: Additionally, [`setState` triggers `render`](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/ogimage.201804100050.png): ☠️be careful of potential infinite loops! ☠️